# Vertical Swiping Between Views iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift

i'm new on Swift and I want to create my resume in an iOS app, I would like to know if it's possible to create a vertical swiping between the different views in the storyboard.

Not a ScrollView thing juste swiping vertical from View 2 to View B

Thanks for awnsers.

Comment: What do you mean ? You want a vertical transition between V1 and V2?

Comment: Imagine the first thing you see is "Welcome to my resume", then you swip to go down (natural scrolling) then you have a another View loaded. Did I explain my self clear ?

Comment: http://anthonyroani.com/ this effect ?

Comment: exactly what i want perfect 1000% matching